# Javascript/jQuery regex for "border-radius" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, css

I'm using jQuery corner plugin for `border-radius` cross-browser support.
This is my function:

```
if(!Modernizr.borderradius){ 
    var s = document.styleSheets;
    for(var i = 0; i<s.length;i++){ 
        var r = s[i].rules || s[i].cssRules;
        for(var x=0;x<r.length;x++) {
            var t = r[x].cssText || r[x].style.cssText;
            if(t.search("radius")>0) $(r[x].selectorText).corner();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, i'm retrieving any element who has border-radius set.

I need a better regex, like this one:

> border(-)?(top|bottom)?(-)?(left|right)?-radius:(.+?);

to detect any variation of `border-radius` and retrieve its value. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for...

```
\bborder(?:-(?:top|bottom))?(?:-(?:left|right))?-radius\s*:\s*([^;"']*)
```

Comment: Got a source for that by any chance? :)

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot! It returns `border-radius:5px,5px` ... how can i isolate the 5px part?

Comment: @x3ro - I wrote it on the spot :) - GionaF - If you want only the first value, then replace ``[^;"']`` with ``[^;"',]``.